Can initrd.img-6.5.0-44-generic be deleted without any consequences?
I am currently running ubuntu 22.04 with a /boot size of 524Mb with 296Mb free. I have already removed old configs and kernels but this initrd.img-6.5.0-44-generic file seems to occupy a lot of space:
total 165260
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    281081 Jun  7 18:29 config-6.5.0-44-generic
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root      4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root      4096 Sep 11 23:23 grub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        27 Sep  5 23:54 initrd.img -> initrd.img-6.5.0-44-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 145793563 Sep  6 11:37 initrd.img-6.5.0-44-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        27 Sep 11 23:23 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-6.5.0-44-generic
drwx------ 2 root root     16384 Jan 31  2024 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    148440 Aug 19  2023 memtest86+x64.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    149504 Aug 19  2023 memtest86+x64.efi
-rw------- 1 root root   8527335 Jun  7 18:29 System.map-6.5.0-44-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        24 Sep  5 23:54 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.5.0-44-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  14304328 Jun  7 19:09 vmlinuz-6.5.0-44-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        24 Sep 11 23:23 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.5.0-44-generic
snnipetr@mahoraga:~$

Is it safe to delete this file? Also, what is its purpose?
Thanks.
EDIT: Added output of lsblk
snnipetr@mahoraga:~$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0          7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1          7:1    0 173.5M  1 loop /snap/brave/436
loop2          7:2    0   173M  1 loop /snap/brave/438
loop3          7:3    0 167.6M  1 loop /snap/chromium/2943
loop4          7:4    0 313.7M  1 loop /snap/code/168
loop5          7:5    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2318
loop6          7:6    0  74.3M  1 loop /snap/core22/1586
loop7          7:7    0  74.3M  1 loop /snap/core22/1612
loop8          7:8    0  67.8M  1 loop /snap/cups/1058
loop9          7:9    0 240.5M  1 loop /snap/firefox/3216
loop10         7:10   0 271.2M  1 loop /snap/firefox/4848
loop11         7:11   0  10.7M  1 loop /snap/firmware-updater/121
loop12         7:12   0  10.7M  1 loop /snap/firmware-updater/127
loop13         7:13   0   7.4M  1 loop /snap/gedit/684
loop14         7:14   0   497M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
loop15         7:15   0 505.1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop16         7:16   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop17         7:17   0  10.2M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1106
loop18         7:18   0  10.5M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1173
loop19         7:19   0  40.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20671
loop20         7:20   0  38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
loop21         7:21   0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
loop22         7:22   0   139M  1 loop 
sda            8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1         8:1    0   260M  0 part 
├─sda2         8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3         8:3    0   123G  0 part 
├─sda4         8:4    0   631M  0 part 
├─sda5         8:5    0 390.9G  0 part 
└─sda6         8:6    0 416.7G  0 part 
sdb            8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1         8:17   0 931.5G  0 part /media/snnipetr/T7
nvme0n1      259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1  259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2  259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3  259:3    0   200G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4  259:4    0 652.6G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5  259:5    0    30G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                      /
├─nvme0n1p6  259:6    0     1G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p7  259:7    0    20G  0 part /home
├─nvme0n1p8  259:8    0    20G  0 part /var
├─nvme0n1p9  259:9    0    20G  0 part /tmp
├─nvme0n1p10 259:10   0   500M  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p11 259:11   0   9.5G  0 part /usr/local


now you have a single kernel, you can't delete it. please, post the output of lsblk command.

have added the required output.

please, post the content of /etc/fstab

NO!
Deleting that file will make your system unbootable.
The initrd.img file (symlinked to initrd.img-6.5.0-44-generic) is an essential part of the boot process.
You must resize the /boot partition,which cannot be done from the installed system. Use a LiveUSB for that, and read a few tutorials first. Back up your data -- resizing partitions can be risky.

Ok thanks, do you know whats the purpose of that file?

That's a great question for Google. It's your initial filesystem, systemd (init), the instructions on how systemd should mount the filesystem and then transfer control over to the mounted filesystem, and much more.
